# How can I change the settings for an application downloaded from the Microsoft Store

Tags: registry, microsoft-store

I'm developping a Windows Application using the Qt Framework. I used to be able to change its settings via the registry but since I published it on the Microsoft Store, it is not possible anymore.

Is there an alternative to update these settings ?

EDIT: I want the user to be able to edit advanced settings that are not accessible through the user interface.

Comment: What you want tends to be a user responsibility.

Comment: Yes of course. I want the user to be able to edit advanced settings that are not accessible through the user interface.

Comment: Apps are more self-contained than traditional programs. Any settings you want users to be able to adjust, you should make a place in the UI to do that.

Comment: Is it documented somewhere ?